# Collect results in for loop when run shell script

Tags: terminal, automator

I try to collect results of "svn info" for selected folders by run shell script,like this:

```
for f in "$@"; do
    svn info $f | tee -a $log_file
done
```

But it's not work. How can I collect each result in for loop?

Comment: Does it work if you run it directly in Terminal? What does "does not work" mean exactly: error message, empty log file, no output? What do you intend to do with the collected result?

Comment: It works with a specified path，but not work in the loop @patrix

Comment: Where does `$log_file` point to? If this is a relative reference (or just a filename), you may not have write permissions in the directory the script is running in. Same for the project names in `$@`.

Comment: A "log.txt" already exists, I'm sure about write permissions. @patrix

Comment: $@ is the input of selected folders in  "Finder.app" of "Run Shell Script"  in Automator

Comment: Use standard debugging techniques then by adding `echo` statements wherever it makes sense :-)

Answer (score -1):

The problem is that "Automator" is not support some encoding such as GB18030.Once your file name encoding with them, they can't be convert to utf-8 , it returns a error.

Comment: Can you add the error message *to the question*? I suspect that the issue is with the shell, not with Automator.

Comment: My mistake, It's not caused by utf-8, but some filename with encoding such as "Chinese(GB18030)", it's can't be convert to utf-8. @patrix